# Do waves need the same amplitude to be coherent?

Tags: waves

I am wondering whether amplitude needs to be constant for two waves in order to be coherent. From my understanding, coherent waves only need a constant phase difference and frequency. Amplitude does not relate to these and therefore coherent waves should be able to have different amplitudes.

However my textbook then describes destructive interference as when two coherent waves with a phase difference of p radians meet, giving a resulting amplitude of 0. This is only possible if the two waves have the same amplitude, such that they cancel each other exactly. So is the same amplitude then a property of coherent waves? Or is this an extra condition needed for destructive and constructive interference? That is does constructive interference need waves of the same amplitude as well?

Comment: your understanding is correct but for *total* destructive interference the two waves should have the same amplitude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way I define "coherent" and "incoherent" superpositions. I am not sure how often people write it down this formally, but in my experience this is what people mean when they use these terms.

Suppose you have $2$ complex numbers, $z_1$ and $z_2$. Since this is physics, $z_1$ and $z_2$ are meant to represent a wave of some kind; they might be the value of two eigenstates at some point in space and time, or the real parts might represent the amplitude of a sound wave at some point in space and time.

A **coherent** sum is just the sum
$$
z_C=z_1+z_2.
$$
There are special cases of coherent sums; if the phase of $z_1$ and $z_2$ are the same, then the two amplitudes **constructively interfere** because the sum has a larger magnitude than either component. If the phase differs by $\pi$, then there is **destructive interference** because the magnitude of the sum of less than the amplitude of either component. If $|z_1|=|z_2|$ and the phase differs by $\pi$, then you get **perfect destructive interference** and the result of the superposition is $0$. If the phase is different from $0$ or $\pi$, generally you'll get something in between -- the magnitude of the sum will be "in between" the sum and the difference of the magnitudes of each component. The main property of a coherent sum is that the answer depends on the relative phases of the components, in addition to the magnitudes of each component.

An **incoherent** sum is the sum of the magnitudes,
$$
z_I=|z_1|+|z_2|,
$$
Incoherent sums often arise when there is some average of the phase of each component before summing the results together. For example, perhaps $z_1$ and $z_2$ represent two independent sources of noise, then it might be that the phase is random but the magnitude is known. Or, quantum mechanically, we could be adding the probabilities for two different measurement outcomes. Destructive interference is not possible. The main property of an incoherent sum is that the answer depends only on the magnitudes of each component and not on the phases.

One way in which quantum mechanics makes use imaginary numbers, is that probability amplitudes are *coherent* sums of complex amplitudes for different ways a process can occur. In regular probability theory, you only ever add *positive* probabilities, which is effectively an incoherent sum. So in quantum mechanics you can get interference effects characteristic of coherent sums, whereas in classical probability theory you do not.